# How do I Survive These Zombies?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

All I would like are some decent strategies for surviving zombies;  I have gotten to 21, but I my goal is to live much longer than this.

Answer (score 3):

Since you don't mention which level you are trying to last longer on it is hard to give you any specific strategies. However there are a few things I usually do (my highest level is 32):

- Use the M4 instead of the shotgun and go exclusively for head shots (still use the pistol for the first two levels). This helps you rack up some early points and gives you a head start.
- This is kind of a given but get to the box as soon as possible and start farming for heavy machine guns, the plasma pistol, or the speciality weapon of the level (IE: the frost gun on "Five").
- Get in the habit of leaving a "crawler" or zombie without legs at the end of every round, by round 15 this is a MUST since you will start completely running out of ammo at the end of every round. You can create crawlers with grenades or by shooting the ground with a "pack-a-punched" laser pistol.
- Perks are your best friend. I always go for Juggernog first, then quick revive. The other perks are great but I find that I usually die while saving someone else and these two help mitigate that problem.
- PACK-A-PUNCH! Each level has a pack-a-punch machine that costs 5000 to upgrade your weapon. After level twenty the zombies are so strong that pack-a-punch is extremely important.
- **Communicate**. Communication is key in this game type, when things start getting out of control it is easy for everyone to start running and get themselves cornered. If you find your window/door/hallway is getting overrun, let your team know! Don't wait until they see your revive symbol to tell them there are zombies behind them! You don't always have to stay together since splitting the horde can be useful on certain levels, but you should at least know where and what your team mates are doing. A good exit strategy and secondary meet up location are also useful if you do need to cut and run. Keep in mind some of the higher rounds can last 30+ minutes so moving to get more ammo may have to happen.

There are plenty of other strategies but these are a few things I find help me survive a little longer. Playing with people you know helps immensely, I find that a lot of randoms would rather die with their points then spend a single one to help open a door or activate a trap. They also tend to try and do there own things as opposed to working as a team and a lot of people are just out for the achievements. This isn't always the case, just what I have found the majority of the time when I play by myself or with one other person.

Answer (score 1):

I see that this question is quite old, but I'll still add a few words.

I'll only say about the tactics that we used in *[Kino Der Toten](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Kino_der_Toten)*, since it's the only map where we got to level 40+.

The following guide is for 2 players:

1. Each player takes 2 windows
2. Let the zombies break through and **knife** them. Letting them in would grant you a few extra points for repairs and a chance to get some power up
3. Repair the windows(barriers) and wait for round 2
4. In round 2 keep on knifing zombies, but don't forget that now you need to knife them **twice** to kill them
5. In round 3 shoot all 8 bullets of your *M1911* in the body of a zombie, then finish it with a knife
6. Approximately at the end of round 3 we had enough money to advance further

   - You **will need** 1750 and 2000 points. The one with lowest score should open the door that is located upstairs(costs 750 points), the other one opens the next door immediately(1000 points)
   - If you are lucky one of these 2 rooms will contain a *[Mystery box](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Mystery_Box)*. If you feel lucky you may gamble and try to get something decent. However, you may wish to stay safe and purchase *[MP40](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/MP40)* which is located downstairs of the last room you opened.
7. Once you are there, stay there till **both** of you have 3750 points. One player takes the top floor(the door and 1 window) and the other player takes the bottom(2 windows). I'd recommend switching every round, because at the top you get a lot more zombies, therefore a lot more points.
8. When both of you have 3750 points(a little less would be fine too), open the next 2 doors(each cost 1250). Then you do want to turn on the power and grab a *[Juggernog](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Juggernog)*(remaining 2500 points)

   - Another option(a much more risky one) would be to purchase the *[Bowie knife](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Bowie_Knife)* for 3000 points. In this case you will still be a 2-hit-target for zombies, **BUT** zombies will become a 1-hit-target for you until round 9. So if you can grab this knife in round 6 or 7, do it!
   - Comparison of the *[Bowie knife](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Bowie_Knife)* to *[Juggernog](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Juggernog)*(*)
9. The next thing you want to do is to activate the *[Teleport](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Teleporter)*. Once this is done, repair all barriers and finish off the remaining zombies.
10. If you have a *[Bowie knife](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Bowie_Knife)* run around and kill the zombies. Each kill will bring you 130 points, so you need to knife 24 zombies to get your money back(24*130 = 3120). Don't forget to get the *[Juggernog](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Juggernog)* **ASAP**.
11. By the second [dog](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Hellhound) round(normally round 10, you can still 1-hit-kill them with a *[Bowie knife](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Bowie_Knife)* up to the third dog round) you should have:

    - A *[Juggernog](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Juggernog)*
    - An *[MP40](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/MP40)* or other full auto weapon
    - Turned on power and ready-to-go *[Teleport](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Teleporter)*.
12. After that rush to the *[Teleport](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Teleporter)* and wait there for the next round to start. Try to kill as many zombies as you can, but don't wait for too long, you **will** be overwhelmed and eventually die. So when you get 1 or 2 hits, use the *[Teleport](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Teleporter)*
13. Once you are up there, throw grenades to the theater, buy some more from the wall and throw again.

    - If you have 5000 points and a weapon (very) low on ammo, *[Pack-a-punch](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Pack-a-Punch)* it
14. When you are being teleported back, you may appear in a room that may contain some power up. If it's there, take it!
15. When back at the lobby, kill **most** of the zombies, but **not all**. Also beware, because zombies may be awaiting you from behind. ***LEAVE A FEW ZOMBIES ALIVE, MAKE CRAWLERS IF YOU CAN***.
16. With a few crawlers you now have enough time to run around, repair all barriers, visit a *[Mystery box](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Mystery_Box)* a few times or drink some perks. And the most important: ***LET THE [TELEPORTER](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Teleporter) COOL DOWN***.
17. Initiate link to pad, activate it, finish off the last zombies and repeat steps 12-17 as long as you can

---

(*)

- Advantages:

  - Single hit zombie kills up to round 9
  - No ammo/reload needed
  - *[Crawler zombies](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Crawler_zombie)* won't release the gas cloud if you kill them with a knife
- Disadvantages:

  - Costs 500 points more
  - You are still an easy kill for zombies
  - You will have to buy the *[Juggernog](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Juggernog)* anyway

---

Weapons that you can get from *[Mystery box](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Mystery_Box)* and do want to keep them:

- *[AUG](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/AUG)*: Decent damage, lots of ammo(30+270), fast rate of fire
- *[Commando](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Commando_%28weapon%29)*: Good damage, lots of ammo(30+270), decent rate of fire
- *[Galil](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Galil)*: Good damage, tons of ammo(35+315), decent rate of fire
- *[RPK](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/RPK)*: Decent damage, tons of ammo(100+400), decent rate of fire
- *[HK21](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/HK21)*: Good damage, tons of ammo(125+500), fairly slow rate of fire
- *[Ray Gun](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Ray_Gun)*: Awesome damage, some ammo(20+180), slow rate of fire, **[wonder weapon](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Wonder_Weapons)**
- *[Thundergun](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Thundergun)*: Instant-kill damage, very low ammo(2+12), slow rate of fire, **[wonder weapon](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Wonder_Weapons)**

Upgraded version of these weapons will feature more damage(except for the *[Thundergun](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Thundergun)*), more ammo and some minor upgrades(such as scopes, dual mags for Commando, increased mag size, etc.).

By following this guide we managed to get to level 40-something. Hope it will help somebody some day :)

Answer (score 0):

After each round, pay constant attention to barriers whenever possible.
Aim for higher points in the beginning rounds so you could have enough money to get what you want.EASY POINTS!
Perks! Always be sure you use them. They can really help in tight situations!
IF YOU GET A GOOD GUN (Raygun, Thundergun) DO NOT TRADE IT! (I assume u are not a noob, so the last one is obvious.)